# Change format of the contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I want to label some of my sections listed in my contents page as 'Introductory'.

I thought I could achieve this by having a dotted box around these chapters in the contents page that marks them as introductory, though I am open to other suggestions.

Have you any suggestions as to how I can edit my contents page to accommodate this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{introsection}
\newcommand*{\introsectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand \theintrosection {\@arabic\c@section}
\newcommand\introsection{%
\@start@introsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                     {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                     {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
}
\let\@start@introsection\@startsection
\patchcmd{\@start@introsection}{\@sect}{\@introsect}{}{}
\def\intronumberline#1{\hspace*{-3.5pt}\numberline{\fbox{#1}}\hspace*{2.5pt}}
\def\addintrocontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{\hspace*{-3.5pt}\fbox{#3}}{\thepage}}}
\let\@introsect\@sect
\patchcmd{\@introsect}{\addcontentsline}{\addintrocontentsline}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\@introsect}{\numberline}{\intronumberline}{}{}
\def\intromatter{\let\section\introsection}
\def\mainmatter{\let\section\ltx@section}
  \let\ltx@section\section
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\introsection{One}
\introsection{Two}
\section{Three}
\section{Four}
\end{document}
```

### Remark

This solution provides a sectioning command `\introsection` that can be used as usual, but adds a framebox around its toc entry. Alternatively you can have the box only around the section number by using line 21 instead of 20.

If you are using the `article` class you can also use the above defined macros `\intromatter` and `\mainmatter` which are meant to be used like the similar and anologous ones of the `book` class:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\intromatter
\section{One}
\section{Two}
\mainmatter
\section{Three}
\section{Four}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

### Addendum

You can of course use another styling of frame by replacing `\fbox` with another macro that fulfills your needs.