# Add box to labeled sections

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir, framed, preamble

I want to add a box to a repeated section of a textbook, which provides question discussions. Is it possible to do it by adding "tex style setting" command(s) to the preamble? I am using the memoir class.

(I require it because I am generating the principal content in my LaTeX file, via Scrivener and Multimarkdown, rather than writing it manually.)

I used tex from [here](http://glurl.co/dCj) to generate some nice Section headings. What I would like to do is to apply similar styling to 2 sections at the end of the chapter—Summary and Discussions—but because these are not sections, as such, I want their headings without the section numbering.

This is the critical tex:

```
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [black!10] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.8cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=cyan!60!white,
        fill=black!90!white,
                    anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.75ex] at (2.9cm,0) {
        \textbf{\arabic{chapter}.\thesection.}
        \color{white}\textbf{T\thesection}
    };
}%
}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\titlebar}{0.1cm}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

This applies a nice styling to my section headings, including the section number. Now I want to apply a similar styling to two sections, Summary and Discussion, which appear at the end of the chapter. But I want those two sections to NOT have section numbers.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SX network, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx! Would it be possible for you to post an example of your efforts, if any? The fastest way is to use the `\fbox` command, but you are probably looking for something more stylish. Could you provide us details of your layout ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148125/change-format-of-the-contents-page/148152#148152) is doing something similar to what you try to achive, I guess. The main difference is that it is about the ToC rather than the sections in the text. But it could be easily extended to your case.

Comment: @Ruben — I can see this example has some similarities. I'm unclear which elements I might need to adapts to produce the selection of the particular elements that I want to style, but I'll experiment a bit and see if I can make something of it!

Comment: What about using a `\section*` and manually adding it to the TOC if desired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it is the best to define a new macro for the crucial sections like

```
\newcommand{\dsection}[1]{\section*{\titlebar*#1}}
```

with a simplified (starred) version of `\titlebar` (see the complete code below).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec,letltxmacro}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\titlebar@@{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
}}
\newcommand\titlebar@{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3cm] {
    \fill [cyan!25] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=cyan!60!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (3cm,0) {
        \textbf{\arabic{chapter}.\thesection.}
    };
}}
\newcommand\titlebar{\@ifstar\titlebar@@\titlebar@}
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\titlebar}{0.1cm}{}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\LetLtxMacro{\LtxSection}{\section}
\newcommand{\dsection}[1]{\LtxSection*{\titlebar*#1}}
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
  \def\secname{#2}
  \ifx\somename\secname
    \LtxSection*{\titlebar*#2}
  \else
    \LtxSection[#1]{#2}
  \fi}
\def\somename{Summary}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section name}
\lipsum[2]

\dsection{Some other Chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Summary}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Note:** As requested the `\desction` format will be applied automatically on every section named "Summary".

[image: example]

### Addendum

To get the section heading in bold you simply need to change the line

```
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\titlebar}{0.1cm}{}
```

to

```
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\titlebar}{0.1cm}{}
```

Comment: thanks; this is helpful and along the lines I was thinking. The critical command is: `\newcommand{\dsection}[1]{\section*{\titlebar*#1}}`, which is implemented in the document, by inserting `\dsection` command. I believe this will work if I insert this tex manually into my MultiMarkdown document, at the relevant section. As a matter of interest is there a way of selecting named sections WITHIN the preamble? I.e. essentially saying implement `\dsection` wherever the section is labelled {Discussion}, which would avoid the need for inserting latex into the MMD file. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful when using the term "labeled" in the LaTeX context. Originally it means that you put a `\label{xyz}` tag in the body, which you can refer to by calling `\ref{xyz}` and its 'cousins'. I Guess you want to *mark* a certain section to declare that it should behave like a "`\dsection`". Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Ideally, I want the `\dsection` behaviour to be adopted by each Summary and Discussion section, WITHOUT having to mark them with latex (I am composing in Scrivener, which generates a LaTex PDF). But I wonder if that may not be possible.

Comment: In using the macro, I've noticed that both section and `\dsection` headings are no longer bold text. Is there a simple way to amend the macro to restore it?

Comment: Yes. And Regarding you other comment: Without telling *LaTeX* what you want to do, it is impossible by definition, because *LaTeX* is doing all the work in this solution right now.

Comment: I understand that _LaTex_ must "do the work" that its told each time; my hope was that I could contain pursuant directions in the preamble—by reference to their name e.g. {Summary}—without having to "mark" (d)sections inside the body of the text.

Comment: Please add an example about how this should exactly look like in the manuscript you are writing, how this "labeling" interface would work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your request. My manuscript is written in MultiMarkdown, with _LaTex_ generated by the software package, Scrivener. With the present solution, I must manually insert the following `<!--\dsection{Summary}-->` as required, while instructing Scrivener to parse the _LaTex_ command. It's this final step that I was trying to avoid, hoping that I could differentiate between the two section styles by referring to the actual section header text, i.e. "Summary", each time it occurs, as it does in each chapter.

Comment: @johnbrc, after quite a while I added a patch for automatically detecting the name "Summary" in the sectional headings. Now, you can use the `\section` macro consistently without worrying about MultiMarkdown instructions you wanted to avoid. Hope it is still helpful these days...